# Parse and Rename text files

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I need to rename all of these files to the 6 character Part Number(306391) on the 3rd line.

Currently i have:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

set first=1

for /f "skip=3 delims= " %%a in (Name.txt) do ( 

   if !first! ==1 (

   set first=0

echo %%a > out.txt
ren Name.txt %%a.txt

 )
)
```

Which finds the 6 digit part number and renames the file to the correct name. But breaks if i use *.txt instead of the actual name of the .txt file. I need it to work for all .txt files in the directory.

Comment: So basically 
for %%I in (*.txt) do (
for /f "skip=3 delims= " %%a in ("%%~fI") do (
if !first! == 1 (
set first=0
ren "%%~FI" %%a.txt

Seems to just not do any of the files for me.

Comment: Almost.  On further inspection, your script needed other tweaks.  I moved my comment to an answer.  Excellent first question, by the way!  It's refreshing to see a new member actually posting code rather than saying, "Write a script for me.  This is what I need it to do."  Glad you didn't do that.  `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surround your `for /f` loop with another `for` loop, then reference the outer loop variable in your `ren` command.  You can also eliminate the need for delayed expansion by using `if defined` for boolean checks.  I put in other tweaks here and there.  Just ask if you want details.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

for %%I in (*.txt) do (

    set first=

    for /f "usebackq skip=3" %%a in ("%%~fI") do ( 

        if not defined first (

            set first=1

            echo %%~nxI ^> %%a.txt
            rem // uncomment this when you're satisfied that it works correctly
            rem // ren "%%~fI" "%%a.txt"

        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on use of "%%~fI" and %%~nxI ^>   I get the logic behind it, but don't understand how that works.

Comment: `%%~fI` means to expand `%%I` to its fully qualified `drive:\\path\\to\\filename.txt`.  It's not really necessary, but it'll make things easier if you decide in the future you want to make your script recursive (changing the first `for` loop to `for /R`).  The `^>` just means echo a literal `>` character to the console, rather than redirecting the output to a file as `>` usually does.  The caret is an escape character.

Comment: What is the use of %%~nxI? Nevermind, i figured it out.

Comment: That explicitly specifies `filename.ext` of `%%I`.  If you were running it recursively, `%%~nxI` would omit printing out the folder names and print only the file name.  See the last couple of pages of `help for` in a console window for full details on tilde notation.

Answer (score 1):

This method should run faster, specially if the files are large, because just 4 lines of each file are read (instead of the whole file):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Process all .txt files
for %%f in (*.txt) do (

   rem Read the 4th line
   (for /L %%i in (1,1,4) do set /P "line4=") < "%%f"

   rem Rename the file
   for /F %%a in ("!line4!") do ECHO ren "%%f" "%%a.txt"

)
```

Comment: I think it'd be the 4th line that needs to be read though.  He's skipping 3.